# Can componentDidMount share data between pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state, next.js

I am still learning React and I apologize if this is a stupid question. I am currently planning about the architecture of my simple App.

I am using Next.js for this project

I have a component that calls the third party API for data every 5 seconds. The data is shared among all pages in the app.

If the component that is fetching the data is not on the main/home page. Are there anyways for `homepage` to get the data it needs from another page?

For example [Below are all pages]

```
index.js // Plain simple page that displays current weather and top music
http://localhost:3000/

weatherforecast.js //Using componentDidMount every 5 seconds to fetch Weather Data
http://localhost:3000/weatherforecast

musicplaylist.js //Using componentDidMount every 5 seconds to fetch Weather
http://localhost:3000/musicplaylist
```

The data shown in homepage has to be refreshed every 5 seconds if there are changes to the following data in `weatherforecast.js` and `musicplaylist.js`

I had this in mind but I have a feeling that it's not the right way to do it.

In the `Homepage.js`, include `WeatherForecast` and `MusicPlaylist` components to fetch the data. If this is the case, it seems like I am repeating the same principle in every page.

I found out about **Redux** which store states as a global object. But how does the state know when to update. But before we getting to state, I am still not sure if components on another page can fetch the data without the user accessing the page.

Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pure React solution, you need to utilize other lifecycle methods available for React. `componentDidMount` is a good spot for making API requests, so you're in the right place to start. However, `componentDidMount` occurs only once, right after the `componentWillMount` and after the DOM is ready with a complete render of the component. Setting your API call to run at a set interval will not trigger a rerender of the component, no any of it's sub components. Instead, use `componentWillRecieveProps` to add your interval request logic. After each interval completes, run `setState` with the new data from the request to update the default state defined in your constructor. As a bonus step to improve performace, follow up with function that returns a bool in `componentShouldUpdate`. This way you can strictly define how and when and what is causing any and all component re-rendering.

Redux is an excellent solution to take care of what you want to do. Personally always use it in my React projects to manage state. Using Redux, you could make your API calls still occur in `componentDidMount`, however the call can hook into your Redux store and update your initial state. The frees you up from have to worry about the local state of your component and how to go about conditionally rendering everything else in your app. Plus Redux abstracts other functions you need, like re-running your fetchToAPI in certain intervals, into their own source (known as Action Creators). Action Creators hook directly in the Redux store so that when one is used, the resulting state diff is passed to Redux's Reducers, which in turn update the application global state. Then all that needs to be done is to have all of your components that need re-rendering on global state change to listen for state changes that occur in the Redux store and conditionally re-render based on the diff of the store from prevState => newProps. This can be setup fairly easy using the boolean check in `componentShouldUpdate`.

Hope this helps! Cheers.

Comment: Hi @DaneTheory, thanks for your answer! 

I am sorry, I have not touched Redux and hence I have a few questions. 

1. To clarify this _"Using Redux, you could make your API calls still occur in componentDidMount, however the call can hook into your Redux store and update your initial state."_ Does this means that componentDidMount located on `another page`(Not rendered by the user) can be called on the `homepage` that is rendered by the user using `Action Creators`.

Comment: Not exactly... if it doen't make sense right away, don't worry. Redux alongside React is diving into the world of Functional Programming and isn't easy for most people to pick up on who are not used to thinking about these kind of programming paradigms on a regular basis. Try to understand how to manage state first with React. Learn about "smart components vs "dumb components". Then, focus on how component inheritance works. This is where you'll start to get the gist on prop delegation, which leads right back around to learning how to best use lifecycle methods. Then, give Redux a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! So to fix my problem as a beginner, I just include the component that fetches data on the page that needs to display the data?

Comment: No. You need to add the additional lifecycle components that delegate when the component needs to rerender. Once you do, pass props down from the component to other components you want to update with this data. No worries man. Its complex stuff. I'll try to help the best I can.

Comment: thank you so much. I am baffled by how amazing this community is. However, is it okay if we leave this thread open? As I would like to go read the React docs again.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the state change notification, refer to below image, and hopefully it is worth one thousand of words:

[image]

Original article [here](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/using-middlewares-in-react-redux-apps-f7c9652610c6).

---

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for sharing the article and the image! However, how am I going to pass data to the view(homepage) if the component that is fetching data belongs to another page(Hence, can I safely say it's not rendered?) 

If it is not rendered, means componentDidMount will not activate to fetch the data.

Comment: Redux is well known for the steep learning curve. Is it OK to use some alternative solutions rather than Redux?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! However, I am only currently using React. But I will look into learning Redux first.

Answer (score 0):

Redux passes the data throughout the connected components via prop, given that a component is mounted whenever it receives new props a new render cycle is initiated so it will reflect your changes, moreover if you dont want to use Redux you can try using the new context api which is easy to implement and will also be suitable for your solution [here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/reacts-%EF%B8%8F-new-context-api-70c9fe01596b) is a tutorial on how to use it

Comment: Hi @RijulZapluri, thanks for sharing about that! I have a few questions though. 

The component in the second page is not rendered by the client, how does the homepage will be able to get the data from the component located on the second page. 

Hence, I can't really say first page's components is connected to second page's components. As the first page is displaying data by using the global state. 

Sorry, if my comment is not clearl.

Comment: Not true. Yes, Redux manages a single source of truth for application state. However, it does so using `CONSTANTS`, `ACTION CREATORS`, `REDUCERS`, and hooking into properly formatted React components following the container pattern with the `react-redux` plugin. It does not force React to do anything. Redux in and of itself can be used as a store for any framework. It's more of a concept/methodology for state management than it is a framework for state. React does a magnificent job with it's built in lifecycle components. Set Redux to update global state. Have React "react" to those changes.

Comment: if your component's interval code is executed even once of making an http request every 5 seconds, it will continue to do so until stoped, although calling setState with give you a no-op ever stating you cannot update a state of an unmounted component but you still could call functions i.e action in case of redux to update your global state, also it would be better to bring your api requests to your parent component which will remain mounted irrespective of other components as your top level component will always remain mounted , you could then pass the data top->down from there

Comment: you pass data down from parent components to child components via props. Another pattern for working with prop delegation is "container" =>   "dumb component", where dumb components are simple pure functions that update only when their container tells them how/when/why to do so. Redux works very well using this setup.

Comment: Rijul you are mistaken. `onComponentDidMount` can fire API requests, yes. But doing so continuously will not trigger component re-renders.  `onComponentDidMount` Runs only once for each component lifecycle, and that's it. React offers plenty of other lifecycle components for managing when/why/how to re-render.

Comment: If there is a interval function and it updates the store everytime the network request are made and new props are passed down renders are bound to happen, he is making new requests every 5 seconds

Comment: I am using componentDidMount() {
    //this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 5000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

Comment: The problem here is that whenever your component unmounts no more http requests are going to be made, as your data needs to be shared amongst component it is advisable that you bring your http requests to the parent component and pass the data down via simple props if it is a child component or via redux if the other component has is isolated

Comment: @RijulZalpuri He doesn't have Redux setup. There is no store maintaining app state, so NO PROPS to delegate from globally. Also, If a component doesn't know how it needs to render or why then props can go wherever they want. To get React components to respond to conditionals by which to re-render, you MUST use React's lifecycle methods. It is literally what they were made to do.

Comment: @DaneTheory i agree with you , what i am saying is considering if he wishes to use Redux

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between pages in `next.js` you will have to use Redux. The idea of Redux is to have a single source of truth. In redux you update the state by calling `actions`. To update redux state you have to create something called `action creators` which dispatches `action` to update the state.

Answer to your question as to if components on another page can fetch data without the user accessing the page is that they do not need to access the data. The components are mounted only when they are accessed, so it will fetch the data when they are *mounted*.

Comment: Hi @illiteratewriter, thanks for looking into this question! Regarding, your second answer, that means I have to mount the component that fetches the data in the page that is accessed(rendered) by the user?